# Conditional tags for Service Fabric Policies

Tags: azure-service-fabric

For production environments we run our Service Fabric apps under gMSA account.

```
<ApplicationManifest>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <Policies>
      <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="MyUser" />
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="MyUser" AccountType="ManagedServiceAccount" AccountName="<some account>"
      </User>
    </Users>
  </Principals>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

When doing local debugging, I simply don't want these policies to be executed since they fail the deploy telling user is not valid or created.

Is there a way to make some of these conditional based on local debugging vs. production ?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the local deployment by changing **Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1**. Adding the following will allow you to use custom app manifests for local development which is useful for scenarios where you need to have relaxed security policies for local dev/test.

```
$ProfileFileName = $(Get-ChildItem $PublishProfileFile).BaseName
$AppManifestBase = "$ApplicationPackagePath\ApplicationManifest"

if ($ProfileFileName.StartsWith("Local") -and (Test-Path "$AppManifestBase.Local.*"))
{
    $localName = if (Test-Path "$AppManifestBase.Local.$ProfileFileName.xml") {"$ProfileFileName"} else {"Local"}

    Write-Host "Copying ""$AppManifestBase.$localName.xml"" to ""$AppManifestBase.xml"""
    Copy-Item "$AppManifestBase.$localName.xml" -Destination "$AppManifestBase.xml" -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The VS developer experience of right click and publish, allows efficient Dev\Test cycles, for standing up environments locally or in the cloud. To avoid the difference or issues with your local machine you can always deploy and debug directly in Azure (So no changes to your manifest needed):

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application#debug-a-remote-service-fabric-application

You should naturally have different environments (Dev, Staging, Prod, ect), that will have environment specific configurations, and you need to use a deployment pipeline (Like Azure DevOps) that modifies your manifest for the targeted environment; I.E. Add the user account properties to your manifest when deploying to prod environment.

Comment: Answer doesn't help me. I have a single applicationmanifest.xml. Parameters are passed based on environment to it (Local.xml or Cloud.xml) but the manifest has policies tag which I want not be executed for local debugging.
You mentioned re-writing/modification to manifest file. How to achieve that ?

Comment: @FrankQ. I think what @aljo-microsoft means is that you need an additional Task in the CI that would modify your **ApplicationManifest.xml** and by adding this user specific configuration. Regarding the situation - I would say that there is no built-in way to add / update **ApplicationManifest.xml** file. You can try to use parameters - `<User Name="MyUser" AccountType="[UserAccountType]" AccountName="[UserAccountName]">` and have them configured differently for each environment (but I am not sure this would work because AFAIK not all parameters in **ApplicationManifest.xml** can be replaced).